# Swap Values from database after performing count

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I know I can do a count from mysql by doing this:

```
Select customer, Count (customer) Numbers from TblOrders group by customer
```

I want to count how many times each customer appears in the Order table. 
After that I want to update Order table by swapping the customer id of the customer with the highest number of orders with another customer with id = 1.

```
Customer | Numbers
1    | 5
2   | 18
3  | 0
```

so here the highest was C2 so it'll swap C1 with C2 now after performing another count, I should get the table below.

```
Customer | Numbers
1    | 18
2   | 5
3  | 0
```

I also know the swapping can be done this way from a little research I've done.

```
Update TblOrders Set Customer = Case when 1 then 2
when 2 then 1
end
where TblOrders in (1, 2)
```

the problem with this statement is that it assumes I already know the two ID's that I'm swapping. but in case I don't know but I want the second one to be the ID with the highest number of orders...how do I go about it?

Comment: Too bad your customer key seems to be a string. Otherwise you could do neat tricks like `UPDATE TblOrders SET customer = 1 + @MaxCust - customer WHERE customer IN (1, @MaxCust)`.

Comment: so if my customer ID's were integer values like say 1,2,3 ..how will I get this to work? does the one in your query represents the ID's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after taking a look at @ MvG's solutions, I came up with my own solution which is below.

```
SELECT customer FROM TblOrders GROUP BY customer ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1 INTO @MaxCust;

Update TblOrders Set Customer = Case 
when 1 then @MaxCust
when @MaxCust then 1 
end 
where TblOrders in (1, @MaxCust );
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to issue an `UPDATE` request which affects all rows that belong to either one of the two customers in question. So the basic idea is this:

```
UPDATE TblOrders
SET customer = IF(customer == 'C1', @MaxCust, 'C1')
WHERE customer IN ('C1', @MaxCust)
```

If your customer IDs were integers, you could abbreviate this to

```
UPDATE TblOrders
SET customer = 1 + @MaxCust - customer
WHERE customer IN (1, @MaxCust)
```

This works because `a + b - a = b` and `a + b - b = a`, so `a` and `b` are exchanged.

My notation above was using a user variable `@MaxCust` to store the ID of the customer to be swapped. Depending on your environment, you might also use application code to enter the correct value into the query. Using a user variable, you could set it like this:

```
SELECT customer
FROM TblOrders GROUP BY customer
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
INTO @MaxCust
```